# How to config wso2 api manager by more nodes?

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I have read wso2 api manager active-active setup, but I want to setup api manager by more than two nodes, for example by three nodes. So I confused in some configs, for example, how to should I **Configure Throttling** part for **3 nodes** in `deployment.toml`

```
[apim.throttling]
event_duplicate_url = ["tcp://<node2-hostname>:<node2-port>"]

[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://<node1-hostname>:<node1-port>"]
traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://<node1-hostname>:<node1-port>"]
type = "loadbalance"

[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://<node2-hostname>:<node2-port>"]
traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://<node2-hostname>:<node2-port>"]
type = "loadbalance"
```

and

```
[apim.throttling]
event_duplicate_url = ["tcp://<node1-hostname>:<node1-port>"]

[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://<node1-hostname>:<node1-port>"]
traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://<node1-hostname>:<node1-port>"]
type = "loadbalance"

[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://<node2-hostname>:<node2-port>"]
traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://<node2-hostname>:<node2-port>"]
type = "loadbalance"
```

And also I want have **two analytics** instance and configure in Nginx, should I add new upstream for analytics in nginx config?
In wso2 api manager document, reverse proxy has no direct relation to analytics, why?and should we config analytics in reverse proxy(Nginx)?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good to have a distributed setup and deploy Gateway nodes as many as you want without deploying 3 All-In-One API Manager nodes. You can learn more about the API Manager profiles and components [here](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/understanding-the-distributed-deployment-of-wso2-api-m/). Further, you can refer to this [doc](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/install-and-setup/setup/distributed-deployment/deploying-wso2-api-m-in-a-distributed-setup/) to set up and deploy a distributed setup.

If your requirement is to spin 3 All-In-One nodes of API Manager, then you have to configure the `event_duplicate_url` and `throttling.url_group` configurations with all three nodes.

Given below is a sample configuration

```
# node1 configurations
[apim.throttling]
event_duplicate_url = ["tcp://<node2-hostname>:<node2-port>", "tcp://<node3-hostname>:<node3-port>"]

...

[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://<node3-hostname>:<node3-port>"]
traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://<node3-hostname>:<node3-port>"]
type = "loadbalance"
```

```
# node2 configurations
[apim.throttling]
event_duplicate_url = ["tcp://<node1-hostname>:<node2-port>", "tcp://<node3-hostname>:<node3-port>"]

...

[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://<node3-hostname>:<node3-port>"]
traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://<node3-hostname>:<node3-port>"]
type = "loadbalance"
```

```
# node3 configurations
[apim.throttling]
event_duplicate_url = ["tcp://<node1-hostname>:<node1-port>", "tcp://<node2-hostname>:<node2-port>"]

[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://<node1-hostname>:<node1-port>"]
traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://<node1-hostname>:<node1-port>"]
type = "loadbalance"

[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://<node2-hostname>:<node2-port>"]
traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://<node2-hostname>:<node2-port>"]
type = "loadbalance"

[[apim.throttling.url_group]]
traffic_manager_urls = ["tcp://<node3-hostname>:<node3-port>"]
traffic_manager_auth_urls = ["ssl://<node3-hostname>:<node3-port>"]
type = "loadbalance"
```

Further, you can follow the [Configuration Catalog](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/reference/config-catalog/#api-m-analytics-configurations) documentation to refer and configure the Analytics section in the API Manager node.

Comment: Thanks.But about config analytics, should  analytics instance configure in Nginx, should I add new upstream for analytics in nginx config?